# how to change the marker icon when click on it here map

Tags: here-api

After loading The heremap i set markers with custom image on it. Then After click in the marker i'm getting the bubble popup. I want to change the marker icon when click on it. How can i change the marker icon when click on it?

Code for showing bubble after click the marker as given below.

```
    map.addObject(group);

  // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
  group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
    // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
    // for all objects that it contains

    var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
      // read custom data
      content: evt.target.getData()
    });


    // show info bubble
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
  }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my application I'm changing the original color of the marker when it is clicked. Have you tried using a markerTemplate, meaning a variable where you store the svg for your marker as a string?

```
 var markerTemplate = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28px" height="36px">... fill="${COLOR}"/></svg>'
```

You can then use e.g. `fill="${COLOR}"` in this string and in your EventListner replace this placeholder with a new color `markerTemplate.replace('${COLOR}', 'rgba(231, 0, 0, 0.7)');`

Hope this helps